# Passing Parameter Values to DSC Configuration from ARM Template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, dsc

I have a simple DSC Config file that contains a credential and string input parameter.  I want this DSC configuration deployed with a VM deployed in an ARM template but am missing the concept of how to pass these two parameters securely.  How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the same error but, after some shenanigans, it is working for me. The important part is the `settings/Properties/SqlAgentCred/password` reference to `protectedSettings/Items/AgentPassword`. Below is the properties node under my Powershell.DSC extension resource in my template.

```
"properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.17",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": false,
        "settings": {
                "ModulesUrl": "https://blobstore.blob.core.windows.net/windows-powershell-dsc/DBServer.ps1.zip",
                "ConfigurationFunction": "DBServer.ps1\\DBServer",
                "Properties": {
                    "SqlAgentCred": {
                            "userName": "user@domain.com",
                            "password": "PrivateSettingsRef:AgentPassword"
                        }
                },
                "WmfVersion": "latest",
                "Privacy": {
                        "DataCollection": "Disable"
                }
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
                "Items": {
                    "AgentPassword": "Pa$$word"
                },
                "DataBlobUri": ""
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will specify protected settings under protectedsettings section. Anything under ProtectedSettings are sent encrypted. Check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/02/26/arm-dsc-extension-settings/ for details.

Comment: This is a good reference and a start but not entirely clear. My DSC configuration has required PSCredential object.  If I simply add a "Credential"  object in the ProtectedSettings.configurationArguments property by adding a userName and password property the DSC configuration fails because it cannot find the Credential parameter.

Comment: Hello, it sounds like what you are doing should work. Would you post the value of protectedSettings you used in your template, and the error reported by the extension? Thanks!

Comment: @NorbertoArrieta I'm having the same problem. Here is my protectedSettings section:`"protectedSettings": {
 "configurationArguments": {
    "SqlAgentCred": {
        "userName": "user@domain.com",
        "password": "password"
   }
    },
    "DataBlobUri": ""
}`

Comment: @sirdank They look OK. What is the error reported by the extension? thanks

Comment: @NorbertoArrieta Sorry, I'm unable to find the original error. I did get it working though. See my answer to this question.