# Passing credentials to DSC script from arm template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, dsc, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a VM with a DSC extension from an ARM template. According to various sources, and even [this SO question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779552/passing-parameter-values-to-dsc-configuration-from-arm-template) I am following the correct way to pass a credential object to my script:

```
"properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
            "type": "DSC",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "settings": {
              "modulesUrl": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('ConfigureRSArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('ConfigureRSArchiveFileName'), '/', parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
              "configurationFunction": "[variables('rsConfigurationConfigurationFunction')]",
              "properties": {
                "SQLSAAdminAuthCreds": {
                  "UserName": "[parameters('SSRSvmAdminUsername')]",
                  "Password": "PrivateSettingsRef:SAPassword"
                }
              }
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
              "Items": {
                "SAPassword": "[parameters('SSRSvmAdminPassword')]"
              }
            }
          }
```

However, when I deploy it, I get this error message:

```
Error message: "The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: The password element of 
argument 'SQLSAAdminAuthCreds' to configuration 'PrepareSSRSServer' does not 
match the required format. It should be as follows 
                {
                    "UserName" : "MyUserName",
                    "Password" : "PrivateSettingsRef:MyPassword"
                }.
Please correct the input and retry executing the extension.".
```

As far as I can see, my format is correct. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: have you tried hardcoding it? i don't see anything wrong with your template

Comment: hardcoding a password? well, I will try it, but it can't be used...

Comment: Unfortunately, it always comes back with the same error message. I have tried changing the apiVersion, changing "properties" to "configurationArguments", changing the credential to be passed entirely in the protectedSettings. It always gives same error message...

Comment: have you tried using github quickstart templates that are doing the same thing and see if they work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that function try to use the paramters that cause the issue. So please have try a check the function in the ps1 file where use the SQLSAAdminAuthCreds. I can't repro the issue that your mentioned. I do a demo for it, the following is my detail steps.

1.Prepare a ps1 file, I get the demo code from [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-dsc-credentials)

```
configuration Main
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [PSCredential]
        $SQLSAAdminAuthCreds
    )    
    Node localhost {       
        User LocalUserAccount
        {
            Username = $SQLSAAdminAuthCreds.UserName
            Password = $SQLSAAdminAuthCreds
            Disabled = $false
            Ensure = "Present"
            FullName = "Local User Account"
            Description = "Local User Account"
            PasswordNeverExpires = $true
        } 
    }  
}
```

2.Zip the ps1 file

3.Download the ARM template and parameters from the Azure portal.

[image]

[image]
  [image]
  [image]

4.Edit the template and parameter file

[image]

5. Try to deploy the ARM template with VS or Powershell
6. Check it from the Azure portal or output.

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what my template had wrong, but thanks for your answer. It must've been malformed in some way, because this works now.